# Cluster Primary Key in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, primary-key, clustered-index

We have a MySQL Database with a InnoDB table containing two integers fields let say `A` and `B`. 
Now suppose we create a *clustered Primary Key* using both indexes A and B.
Everytime the pair A,B is populated we'll have a different index in our DB, so

- A=123 and B=456 will produce a unique index,
- A=123 and B=457 will produce another unique index,
- A=124 and B= 456 will produce another index and so on...

I was wondering if the situation `A=123, B=456` will generate the same index (so is in collision) with `A=456, B=123`. If the answer is NO (as I guess) how MySQL combine those fields in order to obtain a unique index? To generate the unique index, the sum `A+B` is not good for the reason above, the product `A*B` will waste a lot of space in variables furthermore will fail when just A or B is zero, so what's the algorithm used by MySQL (or any other DB) in order to achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you think A = 123, B = 456 is the same as A = 456, B = 123? A unique constraint/primary key makes sure that there are no duplicate records based on the fields in the definition. If A, B is your definition, there cannot be any records in the table that match having the same A, B values. A valid unique constraint means you can uniquely ID each row in the table based on A, B alone.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL indexes preserve column order, and store the value for each column separately.

You can think of it being like a telephone book. The phone book is like an index over two columns: last name, then first name.

In the phone book, they don't add the names together. They store both, separated by a comma. So "Thomas Jay" is a different entry from "Jay Thomas." It's clear that they are separate fields.

It's the same in a multi-column index. The position of the columns matters. They are not added together or multiplied or anything else.

P.S.: Your use of "clustered" is a little bit confusing, because a clustered index already has a different meaning in databases. It means the table is stored in index order. I would suggest using "compound index" when you mean an index with more than one column.

Comment: Sorry maybe my attempt to explain my doubts was too foggy. I meant exactly a Clustered Index inded. I have two coulmns, both integer type, one is Latitudex10000, the other is Longitudex10000 then I have a Place column (string). Now I want to be sure that I have 1 record per each position (with 0,0001° we have about a 16 mt resolution grid), furthermore I want that searches are fast so I created a clustered index using Lon, Lat. I was worry that if Lat and Lon values swaps, the record was the same as 41.1243°,14.6342° is a totally different place from 14.6342°,41.1243°.

Comment: It's up to you to store the values in the right columns. If you swap them, it will be a different entry in the index.

Comment: Thanks Bill, your example of the phone book was illuminating. If I think twice I'm wondering how silly was my doubt. It's true that you never stop learning ;-) Thanks!